# How to convert a MOV created by Fuji F550EXR to AVI?

Tags: windows, video

How to convert a MOV created by Fuji F550EXR to AVI?
The codec used is H264.

VirtualDubMod won't recognize the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution I have found:**

DivX can convert MOV to AVI
http://www.divx.com/en